# Is there a jquery equivalent to xpath's "following"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jquery, I want to move from one paragraph to the next paragraph no matter where that next paragraph is in the dom tree.

Suppose I have a dom tree like:

```
<div>
   <p id="para1">Lorum ipsum</p>
       <div>
           <p id="para2">Lorum ipsum</p>
       </div>
   <p id="para3">
</div>
```

My javascript looks something like, but next() doesn't work because it is looking for the next sibling.

```
var $selectedParagraph = $("p#para2");
var $followingParagraph = $selectedParagraph.next();
```

Is there something I can do besides `.next()` in order to get `p#para3`

Comment: `next()` won't give you para3 ... next() is next sibling only. Not sure what your higher level issue is here but you will need some recursion here I believe. going to need to provide a full explanation of what you are needing to accomplish beyond this simple example

Comment: Something like this? http://www.arronwoods.com/blog/2011/04/jquery-find-next-element-in-dom-by-selector/

Answer (score 0):

I've posted a solution using closest but as @charlietfl noticed, it did not work, so I'm posting a new solution.

As you have elements between your paragraphs, you can't use next.

What I did as to get all paragraph elements, and find in the next element with index greater then current element, here is the code:

```
var $selectedParagraph = $("p#para2"); 
var allP = $("p");
var currentIndex = allP.index($selectedParagraph);
var $next = allP.filter(function (index) { return index == currentIndex + 1; });
```

And here is the fiddle I've used to test:

https://jsfiddle.net/dn01xLn7/

Comment: `closest()` looks up the DOM tree at ancestsors. This can never work , `<p>` can't be a descendant of `<p>` it's invalid html. This is definitely not going to find what OP is looking for

Comment: @charlietfl I've tested with jsfiddle and worked fine

Comment: post link to that fiddle then...doesn't make sense as that's not how closest works and there is no ancestor p

Comment: @charlietfl you're right, sorry. When I was looking for the code I used to test, I created a html with different structure of elements from the example of this question, this is why it probably worked with closest.
I edited with a new solution and the link for the fiddle.
Thank you for let me know about the mistake.